# md-select default value with condition

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

i'm using md-select to pick a year there is a scenario that when you fill up the form in the first time you will get a default value of latest year else you will get the previous value.

here's my view(slim format)

```
md-input-container flex=""
  label Year
  md-select name="type" ng-model="detail.year" ng-change="addYear(detail.product_id)"
    md-option ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year.year}}" ng-selected="detail.year? == null ? year.year : $first"
      | {{year.year}}
```

and here's my controller for iterate the year (coffee format)

```
$scope.years = []
start_year = (new Date).getFullYear()
i = start_year
while i >= 2005
 $scope.years.push(year: i)
 i--
```

my error 
[image]

Comment: `ng-selected` returns a boolean mostly, check the docs.Also why not put this logic in JS, logic in html is code-smell in itself

Comment: I assume you use coffeescript, but in your view you should use javascript (you have a wrong syntax in ng-selected , the ? after detail.year

Comment: @FetraR. coffescript is a javascript

Comment: @harishr ok i will try to figured this out to my controller

Comment: i got it @harishr is right thanks guys

Comment: @wiwit wrong, CoffeeScript is a language that compiles into JavaScript. So it needs a compiler, coffeescript is not a js, this error is about your confusion, you should use js in your dom not cofeescript

Comment: @FetraR. im using coffeescript i dont need to put my whole code just a few and important codes

Comment: @FetraR.you cant right codes without semicolon in native javascript look at my controller you cant see semicolon lol

Comment: @wiwit I know you're using coffeescript in your controller, but you confuse it with js in your dom. I mean ng-selected="detail.year? == 'statement' ? year : 'statement', result an error, you may use ng-selected="detail.year !==null ? 'true statement : 'false statement', the error you show is about the forgotten question point "?" after detail.year which in coffeescript is acceptable but not in javascript :)

Comment: @FetraR. thats why i post my problem here to help me and guide me??

Comment: @wiwit and that's why I say this, to help you understand why this error (unfortunately I couldn't remove the downvote because of the post time)

Comment: @FetraR. its ok lets us help each other next time :) *thumbs up* spread the good vibes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putting comment as answer...

```
   ng-selected="detail.year? == null ? year.year : $first" | {{year.year}}
```

don't add logic in html, keep it in JS files, it will be more easily testable + you dont have to fight with angular syntax support

Comment: can you click up arrow to my question i dont know why  Fetra is mad at me??? lol thanks

Comment: what he/she is trying to say is right, in html use javascript and not coffeescript, thats all to it.. angular works only with javascript expressions in html. this understanding will help you in avoiding this similar mistakes in future